# key based functional fold

Tags: f#, mapreduce, functional-programming

I have a map reduce code for which I group in each of the threads by some key and then in the reduce part merge the results. My current approach is to search for an specific key index in the accumulator and then mapi to retrieve the combined result only for this key, leaving the rest unmodified:

```
let rec groupFolder sequence acc =
    match sequence with
        | (by:string, what) :: rest ->
            let index = acc |> Seq.tryFindIndex( fun (byInAcc, _) -> byInAcc.Equals(by) )
            match index with
                | Some (idx) -> 
                                acc |> Seq.mapi( fun i (byInAcc, whatInAcc) ->  if i = idx then (by, (what |> Array.append whatInAcc) ) else byInAcc, whatInAcc ) 
                                    |> groupFolder rest

                | None -> acc |> Seq.append( seq{ yield (by, what) } )
                              |> groupFolder rest
```

My question is, is it a more functional way to achieve just this?

As an example input to this reducer

```
let GroupsCommingFromMap = [| seq { yield! [|("key1", [|1;2;3|] ); ("key2", [|1;2;3|] ); ("key3", [|1;2;3|]) |] }, seq { yield! [|("key1", [|4;5;6|] ); ("key2", [|4;5;6|] ); ("key3", [|4;5;6|]) |] }  |];;

GroupsCommingFromMap |> Seq.reduce( fun acc i -> 
                                    acc |> groupFolder (i |> Seq.toList))
```

the expected result should contain all key1..key3 each with the array 1..6

Answer (score 2):

From the code you posted, it is not very clear what you're trying to do. Could you include some sample inputs (together with the output that you would like to get)? And does your code actually work on any of the inputs (it has incomplete pattern match, so I doubt that...)

Anyway, you can implement key-based map reduce using `Seq.groupBy`. For example:

```
let mapReduce mapper reducer input = 
  input 
  |> Seq.map mapper
  |> Seq.groupBy fst
  |> Seq.map (fun (k, vs) -> 
      k, vs |> Seq.map snd |> Seq.reduce reducer)
```

Here:

- The `mapper` takes a value from the input sequence and turns it into key value pair. The `mapReduce` function then groups the values using the key
- The `reducer` is then used to reduce all values associated with each key

This lets you create a word count function like this (using simple mapper that returns the word as the key with 1 as a value and reducer that just adds all the numbers):

```
"hello world hello people hello world".Split(' ')
|> mapReduce (fun w -> w, 1) (+)
```

**EDIT:** The example you mentioned does not really have "mapper" part, but instead it has array of arrays as an input -  so perhaps it is easier to write this directly using `Seq.groupBy` like this:

```
let GroupsCommingFromMap = 
  [| [|("key1", [|1;2;3|] ); ("key2", [|1;2;3|] ); ("key3", [|1;2;3|]) |] 
     [|("key1", [|4;5;6|] ); ("key2", [|4;5;6|] ); ("key3", [|4;5;6|]) |]  |]

GroupsCommingFromMap
|> Seq.concat
|> Seq.groupBy fst
|> Seq.map (fun (k, vs) -> k, vs |> Seq.map snd |> Array.concat)
```

Comment: Thank you Tomas for your answer. I have added an example result from the mapper and what I am expecting. So group by is the answer. Of course, then I can simply append in a second reduce. I had it in the tip of the tongue.

Comment: @user3853059 Added one more sample to handle the case you described.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that the mapper does a groupby itself, it just returns the groups in the format I gave you in the sample. Thank you again for your answer